# Rounding all elements in a FieldValueArray

Tags: python, numpy, abaqus

Found a few answers about this but none worked so far. 
I'm trying to round all the numbers in my FieldValueArray to 2 decimals. This is the path in Abaqus I'm using to get my mises FieldValueArray.

```
topCenter=o1.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].elementSets['SET-1']
stress=session.odbs[path].steps['Step-1'].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['S']
area=stress.getSubset(region=topCenter,position=INTEGRATION_POINT,elementType='C3D20R')
mises= area.getScalarField(invariant=MISES)
```

I tried to round by using `np.around`but the error is giving me this message.

```
import numpy as np
mises_round= np.around(mises,2)
File "C:\Abaqus\6.14-1\tools\SMApy\python2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 37, in _wrapit
result = getattr(asarray(obj),method)(*args, **kwds)
AttributeError: rint
```

The same error occurs for

```
mises_round= np.around(mises.values,2)
```

Thanks for any ideas!!

Comment: I will start investigating by checking `mises` and this doesn't seems to be full stack trace of the error

Comment: You're right this was the line above the error:                 
File "C:\Abaqus\6.14-1\tools\SMApy\python2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2277, in around
    return _wrapit(a, 'round', decimals, out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mises` is a FieldOutput object, and the first argument to `around` must be an "array like" object. In FieldOutput you get the data like so:

```
mises.values[i].data
```

So even `mises.values` won't work, because `around` doesn't know to grab the data from the `data` attribute. Therefore, you need to create a new array with the data:

```
mises_round = np.around([v.data for v in mises.values], 2)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it when I'm back at work Monday.